# How can I crop images so as to change their aspect ratio?

Tags: website-design, images, resize, crop

For header images on a site I'm working on we are using 1280x480 px images.

The images I have been given are not 1280x480 px, so I need to crop them, but I can't just crop them any which way - I need the end result to be an 8:3 ratio.

I'm wondering if there is a quick way to do this with a lot of images? Maybe something like [Croppola](http://www.croppola.com/)?

I have Photoshop and Paint.net on my system currently. I'm open to using other software.

Croppola seems almost idea, but I haven't been able to get it to work with the 8:3 ratio (when I go to manual and begin entering values it gets confused...or maybe it is I that am confused).

Comment: you could drag all your photos into a canvas that's sized to your selected dimensions and then just save them back out.  This is usually how I crop a bundle of photos in photoshop at once.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  If you know the dimensions you need them to be (1280x480), why don't you create a photoshop action cropping one of them to that size and then run it on the others?

Comment: I do the same thing as @binky (you should put that as an answer!). With the canvas set to the correct size, you can paste your images into new layers and still retain all the edges that would normally be cropped off, allowing you to skootch each one around until it's in just the right spot., then export your layers to images.

Comment: @vicki I added it as an answer and added your comment in there - if you want, you can edit it and stuff :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could drag all your photos into a canvas that's sized to your selected dimensions and then just save them back out. This is usually how I crop a bundle of photos in Photoshop at once.

1. Make a new 1280px x 480px document.
2. Drag or paste each image onto a new layer.
3. Move each image around until they are in the desired crop position
4. File > Export > Layers to Files

Doing it this way you will let retain all the edges of your images instead of cropping them all off, allowing you edit later if you need to.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful! It sounds like you are manually dragging each image onto a new layer? I'm wondering if there is a way to automate this..., e.g. to say "take x images and insert each image as a new layer on y image" where x are the origin images and y is the image with desired canvas size?

Comment: you can open multiple files as layers: http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/layers/images-as-layers/  but you'll probably want to manually check each image alignment before you crop

Comment: Awesome. I ended up using the script load files into stack per your suggestion. I then created a separate image with the correct canvas size and pasted all of the layers from the stack into that image. I've hid all the layers and am now going through one by one and unhiding them till I've moved them appropriately, rehiding, and moving on to the next!